# How do I get an indexed result list in an enumerated for loop

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to call `spice.str2et(n[i])` for a list of dates (called `UTC`, that I imported from excel). I can get the `spice.str2et(n[i])` but each time it loops it replaces the previous calculated time. I instead need all the `spice.str2et(n[i])` results in an indexed list. (I'm also new to Python/coding, having just started 3 weeks ago.)

I've tried adding `[i]` after my et in my `et =`. I've also looked up on here how to get indexes from enumerated lists but they are all describe how to get the index from the original list. I'm looking to make a new indexed list.

```
import spiceypy as spice

n = UTC.iloc[:,0] 

for i, txt in enumerate(n):

    et = spice.str2et(n[i]) #calculates ephermis time for utc, 
    print(et)
```

This then gives me the list of all the ET I want, as it is overwriting each time it loops (When you do print not indented it just gives the last value).

Comment: It looks like you might just want a list comprehension. Something like `newList = [spice.str2et(txt) for txt in n]`

Comment: 99.99% of users don't know what *ephemeris time (ET)* is so please edit a link into the question that explains it. Bottom line is, (how/) is computing it different to any other type of time? Please don't expect that every user will go Google it for themselves. But if you simply mean "I'm trying to call `spice.str2et()` on a list of datetimes", then just say that  instead, we don't even need to mention ephemeris time at all. Also, `import spice` is missing.

Comment: Welcome to so. Just FYI, the package wasn't even called spice, it was something else (when I searched Anaconda and pip to try to install a nonexistent package 'spice' to repro your issue, I couldn't). SO requires code to be [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before posting, please rerun your code snippet in a clean shell to make sure everything's defined, imported etc. Thanks.

Comment: `UTC` is a pandas dataframe, hence it's better to broadcast the call to `spice.str2et()` to the entire column 0, that's higher-performance. `ets = UTC.iloc[:,0].apply(spice.str2et)`. There is no need to slice a temporary copy of the column `n = UTC.iloc[:,0]`, that just leaks memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
n = UTC.iloc[:,0] 
ets = []

for i, txt in enumerate(n):

    et = spice.str2et(n[i]) #calculates ephermis time for utc, 
    ets.append(et)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might just want a list comprehension. Something like:

```py
n = UTC.iloc[:,0] 
newList = [spice.str2et(txt) for txt in n]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ets = UTC.iloc[:, 0].apply(spice.str2et)
```

Explanation: `UTC` is a pandas dataframe, hence it's better to broadcast the call to `spice.str2et()` to the entire column 0, that's higher-performance than manually iterating as you're doing (or `.iterrows()`, which should also be avoided).

- There is no need to slice a temporary copy of the column `n = UTC.iloc[:,0]`, that just leaks memory, or creates an unnecessary object.
- **Please take a quick skim through the pandas tutorial [Essential Basic Functionality: Function application](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#function-application)**